# something‘s wrong with the vertex groups hook

Tags: vertex-groups, hook-modifier

I create two vertex groups with the same vertexes.

[image]

and then hook groups to the same action，but I get the different results

[image]

[image]

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something different about your vertex groups. I would recommend doing it again from the beginning. Everything works as expected if i try to replicate the issue - if I create two identical vertex groups they act identically with the same Hook modifier. It seems in the first case in your scene the transition is soft so one of the groups must have some different weights. If you just click "Select" to check if the groups are the same, you might see the same vertices selected even though the weights are different.Check the groups in the Weight Paint mode:

[image]

Comment: think you very much!!! i'm new here

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Suzanne:

[image]

She has a hook modifier.  No vertex group is specified, meaning the modifier is acting on the entire mesh.  Yet only a single vertex is being affected by the hook modifier.  What gives?

The answer is that a hook modifier actually has several different ways by which it is limited.  Yes, you can limit it with a vertex group.  But it is also limited by which vertices are assigned to the hook.  Enter edit on your meshes and notice that new buttons appear on the modifier:

[image]

And if we click on that "select" button, we can select all vertices that are currently assigned to the modifier, and discover that I only have one vertex assigned.  That is why the hook modifier is acting on only a single a vertex.

To assign further verts to the hook modifier, I can select those verts then hit the assign button.

So we can have two identical meshes, with two apparently identical hook modifiers, but with different *assignments* stored inside of those modifiers that lead to different behavior.  This is not the only way that they can be different-- they may have different inverses (set by resetting the hook in edit).  And other modifiers similarly store hidden details that affect how they function.  Corrective smooth, surface deform, mesh deform, Laplacian deform all store invisible bind data that means that these can act differently even with identical settings and meshes, and of course soft body and cloth are modifiers that depend on much, much more than the mesh that they run on or their own settings-- they depend on their *history*.